# Does Cobalt support client certificates?

Tags: cobalt

In [Cobalt's](https://cobalt.foo/) /net directory there is some client certificate related code but it seems to be unused. Does Cobalt support client certificates?

Answer (score 0):

No, Cobalt does not currently support client certificates.